# I have an error in reading the XML data of a given URL

Tags: java, xml, url, xmldocument, xmldom

I use the following code to read the XML data of a given URL but i have an error and i don't know how to fix that.
I want to read the contents of a given URL but on XML not in HTML. any help will be appreciated.

the code :

```
package search;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;


public class Process{
    public static void main ( String [] args ) throws IOException{

        URL xmlUrl = new URL("http://www.yahoo.com");
        InputStream in = xmlUrl.openStream();
        Document doc = parse(in);

    }

    public static Document parse (InputStream is) {
        Document ret = null;
        DocumentBuilderFactory domFactory;
        DocumentBuilder builder;

        try {
            domFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            domFactory.setValidating(false);
            domFactory.setNamespaceAware(false);
            builder = domFactory.newDocumentBuilder();

            ret = builder.parse(is);
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            System.err.println("unable to load XML: " + ex);
        }
        return ret;
    }
}
```

### The Error

```
[Fatal Error] :7:17: The entity "lrm" was referenced, but not declared.
  unable to load XML: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 7; columnNumber: 17; 
  The entity "lrm" was referenced, but not declared.
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the tenets of XML parsing is that the input data should be XML. However, from your example URL, Yahoo.com appears to be HTML5, which isn't XML and isn't even a direct descendant of SGML (unlike HTML and XML) and thus probably not parsable as XML by any commonly found parser. HTTP can be used to return almost any content type (HTML, XML, JSON, binary etc.) but the example given is HTML. If you rigged that example up to an URL that returned a content type of XML, your parsing errors would likely go away.

If they were using XHTML, you'd probably be ok as that is HTML that conforms to XML structure rules but even then, it's too easy to break XHTML without realising it.

Even regular HTML, although a descendant of SGML won't necessarily parse as XML as it can have non terminated tags etc.

In general, HTML parsers are far more tolerant than XML ones of deviations from specifications, so if you limited your usage to just XHTML sites, you'd still get a lot of parser failures.

Comment: so, there is no way to retrieve the XML file instead of html ? i know websites which use the rss feed and it use XML as i think, will i can deal with it only ??

Comment: Well yes, if you're tapping into an RSS feed, that's great. HTTP can be used to retrieve all kinds of contents. But the example posted returns HTML5 content, which won't parse.

Comment: sounds like what i said on your last question. there is a syntax error, because you have html, not xml

Comment: but, i wanna process the xml data, so, what can i do to retrieve the xml data not the html datafrom a website that uses rss feed , as this feeds will be in XML not HTML as i think

Comment: Well, you need to put an URL in your code that resolves to an XML content delivery system. Try http://feeds.bbci.co.uk/news/science_and_environment/rss.xml